# Installing Packages in R - mgarch

Tags: r, time-series, package, economics

im trying to install mgarch package from Github. I downloaded the zip file: mgarch_0.00-1.tar.gz

I tried this procedure:

install.packages('package.zip', lib='destination_directory',repos = NULL)

as said here [Manually Downloading and Installing Packages in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806705/manually-downloading-and-installing-packages-in-r])

But didnt work

Another procedure was: [How to install development version of R packages github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656016/how-to-install-development-version-of-r-packages-github-repository)

As suggested at this link  i had to install devtools from Hadley.

```
install.packages("devtools")

library(devtools)

dev_mode(on=T)

install_github("ggplot2")
```

I did, and nothing happened.

As a begginer im really lost. Just  want  something to clear my way, because i need to run an BEKK GARCH Model.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 library(devtools)
 install_github("vst/mgarch")

 library(mgarch)
```

installs this package https://github.com/vst/mgarch

is that the one you want?

the syntax for `install_github` is (usually) `install_github("username/repository")` this is rather poorly documented in the `?install_github` documentation

Comment: i did....and the result was... ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mgarch' * removing 'C:/Users/Myname/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/mgarch' Erro: Command failed (1) –

Comment: do you have rtools installed? Read this https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes... and i folowed this procedure :library(devtools)
build_github_devtools()

#### Restart R before continuing ####
install.packages("devtools.zip", repos = NULL)

# Remove the package after installation
unlink("devtools.zip")             and i did : install_github("username/repository")  The message was: it wasnt possible to find function "install_github"

Comment: when you restarted R did you type in `library(devtools)` again? every time you start R you need to load your required packages.

Comment: yes... i do `library(devtools)`  the message error is: ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mgarch'
another error message is : Erro: Command failed (1)