# biotools package fails to install

Tags: r, package, failed-installation

I have tried to install the [biotools package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biotools/index.html) on my desktop so that I can run a box's M test for homogeneity of covariance. However I get the following error message.

> ERROR: failed to lock directory
>   ‘/Users/lmil8126/Library/R/3.2/library’ for    modifying
>
> Try removing ‘/Users/lmil8126/Library/R/3.2/library/00LOCK-biotools’
>   Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘biotools’ had
>   non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘/private/var/folders/0q/n377y94n4gzd0zlntfsq1jnh2ymcwz/T/Rtmp8fhiFd/downloaded_packages’

The package works fine on my laptop, which is Mavericks, but my desktop is Yosemite.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: Did you try to remove `/Users/lmil8126/Library/R/3.2/library/00LOCK-biotools`?

Comment: I assume you tried installing with install.packages() ? You can also download the package from here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biotools/index.html and install it manually. In RStudio you can do this by Tools > Install Packages > Install from (change value in dropdown list). If you don't use RStudio see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14806790/1117932

Comment: yes Pascal I did delete the File from the R library. But it still won't attach properly. When I tried to attach the package it got to the point where it

Comment: Yes I deleted the lock folder from the R library. Still wouldn't run. Then removed the package and tried a manual install with code AND via the method suggested by Expecto after downloading the mavericks binary version of biotools. Nothing works. Still get all the error messages referred to above and the session aborts and shuts RStudio down automatically around about the time when the 'tkrplot' section of the package is being loaded. I think this must be a Yosemite problem because the package works fine on my laptop with Mavericks.