# Install ngramrr package

Tags: r, package

I have 3.3.2 R version and I would like to installe this package "ngramrr" ( https://github.com/chainsawriot/ngramrr)  which is compatible for R version 3.0.

When I try to istall it :

```
> install.packages("ngramrr")
```

I get this error :

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/A579856/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ngramrr’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)
```

I don't know why , I have 3.3.2 R version.

Can you help me to resolve this problem please?

Thank you

Comment: [That](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14806790/5784831) should help...