# Can't install packages in R Studio (Mac M1/M2)

Tags: r, macos, installation, package, tar

I have recently bought a Mac (M2) and I originally only had an issue installing bioconductor packages in R. I understand this was an issue associated with the new Mac architecture. To deal with this I uninstalled R (for Apple silicon) and re-installed the Intel version of R for Mac. I'm now unable to install any packages in R (from within R studio) with command:

```
install.packages("readr")
```

I keep getting this error message:

> sh: tar: command not found
> Warning in install.packages :
> error in running command
> Warning in install.packages :
> 'tar' returned non-zero exit code 127
> Error in install.packages : file ‘/var/folders/4m/qkbb2hwd1t12v_11mjcphv300000gp/T//RtmphSqv5y/downloaded_packages/utf8_1.2.3.tgz’ is not a macOS binary package

So I understand this is an issue with the tar command. This same question was asked previously ([Cannot install R packages on Rstudio - MacBook Pro M1 chip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76929900/cannot-install-r-packages-on-rstudio-macbook-pro-m1-chip)) however when the user followed the advice given (brew install tar) and then checking the version with tar --version I get this output:

> bsdtar 3.5.3 - libarchive 3.5.3 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.0.5 bz2lib/1.0.8

And the error with installing packages remained. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what version of R did you install exactly? If you have an M2, you should be installing `R-4.3.1-arm64.pkg` -- not the intel version -- from https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/.

Comment: Hi, yes originally I had R-4.3.1-arm64.pkg installed but I used Bioconductor packages and these are unavailable with that version of R. This post (https://bioboot.github.io/bggn213_F21/class-material/bioconductor_setup/) suggested using the Intel version instead (R-4.3.1-x86_64.pkg), even when using a M1/M2 mac.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you are downloading the binary package in tgz format, and then something goes wrong. You can try building the package locally using `install.packages("readr", type = "source")`.
It would also be helpful to know what you get when you do: `getOption("pkgType")`

Comment: Hi thank you for your quick reply! When I tried install.packages("readr", type = "source") I recieved this error: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R: line 143: exec: sh: not found. Also getOption("pkgType") gives the result "both".